# I can't ping from my server to google.com, how can I diagnose issue?

Tags: networking, ping

I'm on my server and I can't ping anything outside.  I tried for example google.com. How can I diagnose this issue? I can ping my localhost (ping works)

This is my traceroute to google.com:

```
[root@ip-10-112-63-16 tony]# traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (74.125.113.147), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

And this is the result of route -n:

```
[root@ip-10-112-63-16 tony]# /sbin/route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.112.62.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.112.62.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

And these are my iptables:

```
[root@ip-10-112-63-16 tony]# /sbin/iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: You need to first figure out how far you can reach. Can you ping your switch? Ping your gateway? Ping your next hop?

Comment: Also, is this a DNS issue or a network communications issue?

Comment: i have no idea how to figure that out.  the server is an EC2 instance though

Comment: network communications issue because i did a dig on google.com and then tried to ping the IP

Comment: Perform a traceroute to google.com. Post results.

Comment: ok i posted the traceroute

Comment: Post results of "route -n"

Comment: Ok I posted the result of route -n

Comment: can you ping 10.112.62.1? Also, post output of "iptables -L"

Comment: pinging that IP hangs, iptables look normal but im posting them

Comment: You apparently can't ping the gateway in EC2 instances (just tried it) so that's probably not a worry, especially since you can connect to your instance.

Comment: Since this is EC2, looking at iptables isn't sufficient.  Have you done something weird with whatever Security Policy is set for that instance?

Comment: Someone else set up this instance.  Actually I built a new instance myself and everything worked fine.  Still a bit curious why this one has broken. I've never experienced this before.  I don't see any security settings in the panel that would cause this but it's possible someone else screwed up the instance. Crazy that it's pretty hard to debug this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this (http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1145) EC2 blocks ICMP by default. You need to issue this command to allow it

> ec2-authorize default -P icmp -t -1:-1 -s 0.0.0.0/0